# Read values from xml using xsl

Tags: xslt

```
 <checkpoints checkpoint_count="1">
      <checkpoint checkpoint_name="New CheckPoint" ignore_blank_lines="false" modified_complexity="false" checkpoint_date="1999-08-31">         
          <file file_name="Plugin.java">
            <metrics metric_count="15">
              <metric id="M0">57</metric>
              <metric id="M1">17</metric>
              <metric id="M2">0.0</metric>
              <metric id="M3">3</metric>
              <metric id="M4">47.4</metric>
              <metric id="M5">1</metric>
              <metric id="M6">5.00</metric>
              <metric id="M7">1.20</metric>
              <metric id="M8">20</metric>
              <metric id="M9">CheatsheetsPlugin.getImageDescriptor()</metric>
              <metric id="M10">1</metric>
              <metric id="M11">21</metric>
              <metric id="M12">2</metric>
              <metric id="M13">1.05</metric>
              <metric id="M14">1.00</metric>
            </metrics>
        </file>
 </checkpoint>
</checkpoints>
```

This is my xml file. I want to read value of `metric id='M14'`. ie. **1.00**

How to read the content of this tag?

Comment: Using XPath: `id('M14')`. But you give very little information. Why do you want to read the value? What happens with it? Consider learning some XSLT basics, like e.g. from http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Output/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/*/*/metric[@id = 'M14']/text()
```

This selects any child text node (in this case just one) of any `metric` element that is a grand-grand-child of the top element and whose (of the `metric` element) `id` attribute has as string value the string `'M14'`.